# How to pass state to jsx, render it and update when state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, variables

I'm new to React but I'm having a lot of fun with it. I wanted to add a Fun Facts-generator to the "About me" section of my portfolio, and I figured out how to make it work through the console, but I'm having no luck passing the generated fact to the `return()` part of my component.

I'd like to write out the content of the variable `funFactoid` on the page every time the user clicks the button, through a `<p>`-tag for example.

This is currently what my code looks like (I've removed parts irrelevant to my question):

```
function About(props) {

  function funFact() {

    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { 
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    }

    const randomNumber = randomIntFromInterval(0, 4);

    const factArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

    console.log(factArray[randomNumber]);
    let funFactoid = factArray[randomNumber];
  }

  return (
    <div>
      
      <button onClick={funFact}>Click me for a fun fact!</button>
      <p>{ funFactoid }</p>

    </div>
  )
}
 
export default About;
```

I'm sure it's a ridiculously easy fix, but I'm self taught so I I've probably just missed some important part that explains how to do this.

Thanks in advance for helping me out! This is the first time I've come across a coding problem I haven't been able to solve through Googling, so I'm super thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The var `let funFactoid` is not in the same scope as your return function, other than that you should not use let, but the useState hook to set values you want to render:

```
function About(props) {

  const [funFactiod, setFunFactoid] = useState("")

  function funFact() {

    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { 
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    }

    const randomNumber = randomIntFromInterval(0, 4);

    const factArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

    console.log(factArray[randomNumber]);
    setFunFactoid(factArray[randomNumber]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      
      <button onClick={funFact}>Click me for a fun fact!</button>
      <p>{ funFactoid }</p>

    </div>
  )
}
 
export default About;
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that. I still have some reading to do in the documentation I guess ;)

Comment: You're welcome! If you could do us all a favour and mark the answer as correct, it would be awesome!

Comment: If you don't mind, I tried the solution but it didn't work for me. Would you happen to know why it says `funfactoid, setFunFactoid` is declared but never read and `setFunFactoid`is not defined within the function? I imported useState from React but maybe I'm still missing something

Comment: Ok so first off, I wrote `funFactiod` and not `funFactoid`, so change that. And for the second error, you have to change `setFunfactoid(factArray[randomNumber])` to `setFunFactoid(factArray[randomNumber])` (Uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

I had just one suggestion

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}

function funFact() {

const factArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

const lastIndex = factArray.length - 1

const randomNumber = randomIntFromInterval(0, lastIndex);

console.log(factArray[randomNumber]);
setFunfactoid(factArray[randomNumber]);
 
}
```

You can add a `lastIndex` variable to keep away errors so you can change the array without worrying about the max number.

Comment: Hey that's awesome, thank you so much! Never knew about that